# What data should be returned from service to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular and defined a Service and a Controller.

When there is an error I need to display a message to the user.
Should I handle errors on controllers or on controllers and services?

Should a service returns $http and handle everything on controller?

```
function postService($http, $log, settings) {
  return {
    get: function () {    
      return $http.get("/api/recent-posts");
    }
  }
}
```

Or should a service return only pieces to controller:

```
function postService($http, $log, settings, $q) {
  return {
    get: function () {    
      return $http.get("/api/recent-posts")
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    }, function (response) {
      $log.error("Service Error");
      return ($q.reject("Service Error"));
    });
  }
}
```

On second option I am not returning full $http information to controller.

Comment: you should return promise from service which then handover to controller for further processing where you can handle all your business login include valid/invalid

Answer (score 0):

Generally

> service is for API calls and 
>   Controllers are for writing/modifying the data(from APIs) using the required logic to show on UI.

Comment: Yes, I know ... But what should a service return to controller? Everything that $http returns? I see different approachs on web so this is why I am asking ...

Comment: There is no need to return everything which service returns. You can jus return the result.data(if "result" is the object returned from the service) and ignore the remaining values which are not even necessary.